# Java design alternatives to if-else with instanceof

Tags: java, json, architecture, software-design, instanceof

Our Java application uses [Google Guava EventBus](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained) in the backend for communication. Some of those events are sent to client-side using Jersey's [server-sent events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) [support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/sse.html) to enable notifications. Client-side is only interested in certain kinds of events and those events are sent to client-side in JSON format.

Currently we're using `if-else` with `instanceof` to handle the JSON body generation in a giant method. `UIEvent` is only a marker interface which used as a filter.

```
@Subscribe
public void handleEvent(final UIEvent event) {
  if (event instanceof A) {
    A a = (A) event;

  } else if (event instance B) {
    B b = (B) event;

  } ...
}
```

This code starts to get messy when more and more events are added to the system. After some research, there are some alternatives but not good enough.

1) Reflections.

Using reflections means we can use a declarative way to retrieve data from event objects without knowing the exact type. But using reflections is not type-safe and can be messy when dealing with nested path, e.g. `a.b.c`.

2) Polymorphism

Polymorphism looks like a good alternative to `instanceof`, but does really work in this case. Using polymorphism means adding method like `toJSON` to `UIEvent` interface. But this reverts the dependency flow and exposes UI details to event bus.

3) Wrapper classes

I'm also thinking about using event wrapper classes to encapsulate the JSON body building logic in separate classes. Then in the event bus's `handleEvent` method, I can get the type of event object and find the wrapper class using naming convention, then construct wrapper class instances, invoke `toJson` method to get the JSON body.

```
public class AWrapper {
   public AWrapper(A a) {

   }

   public Object toJson() {

   }
}
```

This is by far the most reasonable approach I can think of.

Need suggestions and ideas.

Comment: [Polymorphism](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html) is a standard pattern here.  However, if possible you should just try to test a field in the event and switch on that.

Comment: Polymorphism has my vote as well. But having a method like `toJson` on the interface locks you into using json. Another solution you could consider, is to add a method that returns a generic set of data properties (e.g. a `Map<String, Object>`), that you then use to serialize to json.

Comment: Modern libraries like Jackson or Gson can serialize POJOs to JSON effortlessly, so you don't need special methods for that. Why not create a custom annotation that distinguishes between events that are internal and events that would need to be broadcast to clients? You would then use reflection in `handleEvent()` to inspect whether the annotation is present or not.

Comment: @markspace The reason I don't want to use polymorphism is because the event classes are in core module and also used by other modules, but serialization to JSON logic is in API module. I don't want the core module to know about API module.

Comment: @MickMnemonic The JSON body sent to client-side has a pre-defined format, so the simple JSON serialization is not enough, data transformation is required. I didn't consider custom annotation before, looks like a good choice to distinguish between different events.

Comment: Eclipse frequently uses a pattern that you could borrow for your option 3: adapters, and especially the related `IAdaptableFactory` and `IAdapterManager` types. This pattern can be used to adapt your event types to type that can be serialized to your chosen format, without "polluting" your event class with additional responsibilities.

Answer (score 1):

I believe[Google Guava EventBus](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained) was precisely designed so you didn't have to define such method with many if-else-if's:

> Some have proposed a generic Handler interface for EventBus
> listeners. This runs into issues with Java's use of type erasure, not
> to mention problems in usability.
>
> ...
>
> Due to erasure, no single class can implement a generic interface more than once with different type parameters. This is a giant step backwards from traditional Java Events, where even if actionPerformed and keyPressed aren't very meaningful names, at least you can implement both methods!

By creating your own marker, you are re-creating the problem they were trying to avoid.

### To me, this is how Guava suggests to use it:

```
EventBus eventBus = new EventBus();
eventBus.register(new Object(){
    @Subscribe
    public void handleEvent(A a) {
        System.out.println("a");
    }
});

eventBus.register(new Object(){
    @Subscribe
    public void handleEvent(B b) {
        System.out.println("b");
    }
});

...

eventBus.post(new A());
eventBus.post(new B());
```

One handler method per event type. **Obviously, the subscribers don't need to be in anonymous classes like in this example**.

#### Other examples

http://tomaszdziurko.pl/2012/01/google-guava-eventbus-easy-elegant-publisher-subscriber-cases/